# Unrestricted grammar to generate $a^{n(n+1)/2}$

Tags: formal-grammars

I have been asked to find a grammar that will generate the language $a^{n(n+1)/2}$, where $n\ge1$ as an exercise. Any idea on how to set up such grammar? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help with conceptual questions but just solving homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really help you.

Comment: Mr David,
At the very beginning  I was trying to generate a grammar using the hint that was provided as an answer. However I thought of a different way to solve my problem and i was trying to figure out how to decrease the number of "a" into half. 
I have to apologize because I was not clear  what I actually wanted to ask. Moreover, I figure out a way that could be solved and I posted as an answer at the question, as well as the unrestricted grammar. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Very close to the language [$a^{n^2}$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71567/unrestricted-grammar-to-generate-an2)

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:*

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m}n=\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an idea while trying to solve my question. 
The length of the input string should be n(n+1)/2 => (n^2 + n)/2.
We know how to generate a unrestricted grammar for the language a^(n^2)b^n.In this problem, each b will be replaced by an a. Thus, the string's length will be (n^2 + n) . However we need half of this string. In order to Decrease the number of a , I changed the rules such as that a new symbol,D, would be created and it would be responsible for the deletion of an a.
Basically the grammar looks like this:

- S -> LS'R
- S'-> XS'YB
- S'-> e
- BY-> YDB
- XY-> YaX
- aY-> Ya
- Xa-> aX
- LY-> DL
- DR-> RD
- XR-> R
- La-> aL
- BR-> Ra
- LR-> e
- Da-> e
- DY-> YD

Comment: Nice. Glad you figured it out and thanks for posting it as an answer!